# How to create a new column in a pandas df based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I am working on a programming assignment and am seeking some help out here as the course openly encourages us to.

In the course of solving one of the problems, I need to find out from a dataset of children having received various vaccinations and their medical history the subset of children who both have (a) gotten chickenpox (HAD_CPOX, yes or no) AND (b) were vaccinated against chickenpox (P_NUMVRC, number of doses of chickenpox vaccine received)

The question is asking us to generate ratios by sex.
So far I have:

- Extracted the csv and turned it into a pandas dataframe
- Created a subset dataframe titled 'subset_chickenpox' from the previous one containing only the relevant information (HAD_CPOX, SEX, P_NUMVRC)
- Further split each of these subsets between male and females resulting in the dataframes subset_COP_male and subset_COP_female and dropped NAs

**I am now seeking to create a new column 'failedvax' in each of these subsets based on the following logic, containing two conditions:**

- If the column HAD_CPOX is equal to 1 AND P_NUMVRC is not 0, then failedvax is True.
- Else failedvax is False.

I have tried various approaches, first using np.where which generated an error, and now I tried a different approach using a function, which also yields an error.

```
 #Chickenpox question
#Relevant variable in original df is HAD_CPOX, sex is SEX, having been vacced is P_NUMVRC 
#So first we subset for all these selecting all rows where df columns are these.
subset_chickenpox=df.loc[:,['HAD_CPOX', 'SEX', 'P_NUMVRC']]
#We are asked to calculate the ratio of children who were vaccinated but did get it 
#versus the ratio of children who were vaccinated and did not get it
#In other words we want the ratio of rows where HAD_CPOX=1 and P_NUMVRC is 0 
#vs the ratio of columns where HAD_CPOX=2 and P_NUMVRC != 0
subset_chickenpox.dropna()
#Because question by sex we do sex subsets
subset_COP_male=subset_chickenpox[(subset_chickenpox['SEX']==1)]
subset_COP_female=subset_chickenpox[(subset_chickenpox['SEX']==2)]
subset_COP_male.dropna()
subset_COP_female.dropna()
#I will now calculate a new column: failed_vax
#First we need to create a function to hold our conditional logic
#If HAD_CPOX=1 AND P_NUMVRC != 0 then failed_vax is true
def failed_vax(x):
    if subset_COP_male['HAD_CPOX']==1 & subset_COP_male['P_NUMVRC']!=0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
subset_COP_male['failed_vax'] = subset_COP_male.apply(failed_vax)
```

From this I get

````
``` TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool] ```
````

An example of the data (from subset_COP_female after dropping NAS) would be

````
``` 
INDEX HAD_CPOX  SEX P_NUMVRC
3   2   2   1.0
4   2   2   0.0
6   2   2   1.0
7   2   2   0.0
20  2   2   1.0
... ... ... ...
28437   2   2   1.0
28440   2   2   1.0
28446   2   2   1.0
28452   2   2   1.0
28454   2   2   1.0
```
````

Thank you very much in advance! Would appreciate any pointers towards creating a new column based on the logic explained above. It's also not the first time I run into such a problem so I'd love to understand a bit more about why my code isn't working.

Best regards to all

Comment: try putting ```int(subset_COP_male['P_NUMVRC'])```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
subset_COP_male['failed_vax'] = subset_COP_male['HAD_CPOX'].eq(1) & subset_COP_male['P_NUMVRC'].ne(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works but I do get a warning /var/folders/8v/zkdpsxrj3l389d2bxhgyxjn80000gn/T/ipykernel_40760/167510000.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
Any idea what this relates to?

Comment: Do you need to do this separately for male and female? Or is the criteria the same independently of gender? (I ask because it influences my solution of the error)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your new column before you create your subsets.
This should work:
First add a new column 'failedvax' filled with 'False'.
Then apply the condition your asking, assign 'True' to the new column when the condition is met.

```
df['failedvax'] = False
df.loc[(df['HAD_CPOX']==1)&(df['P_NUMVRC']>0),'failedvax'] = True
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried this but I am getting a warning that I cannot copy fully in the comment but references https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy